# IIS Worker Process Recycle is periodically breaking MySQL client in .Net Core 3 application

Tags: mysql, iis, .net-core

The automatic daily IIS recycle of worker process is occasionally (every 5-10 days) breaking the ability of the application to connect to AWS Aurora (MySQL) Server.

After the recycle - we get these errors. Other worker processes in the same IIS instance continue working just fine - all configured similarly. The errant worker process then becomes hung and IIS itself has to be recyled to fix the problem.

Oracle MySql.Data.MySqlClient .Net Core Class Library 8.0.20

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
...

More information from logs...
It would appear that it handles the first few new requests - then has problems - so might be coincidental - no event log errors that correspond to the problem though...

Connection Pool is using defaults:
Max Pool Size 100
Connection Lifetime 0

Additional Information: Logs show before complete breakdown that some executions are fine, others taking many seconds instead of less than 100ms - in the same worker thread. So something pool related might be going awry or the instance.

Definitely going to adjust when the cycling occurs.

Comment: The REALLY weird thing is that another DLL in the same worker process is able to connect using MySQL and isn't affected by the problem.

Comment: are the max connection high enough , check the error log for mysql

Comment: server side allows 1000 connections - and monitoring shows max 150 used

Comment: the problem can be that the operating system doesn't allow that many coennctions, so there could be en entry in the event log

Comment: Nothing in the event logs. I hate mysteries like this.

Comment: i would have guessed some network issues, you could add some netwrk testting to your code when this happens, to see if any other adresses are possible

Comment: MySQL has its own forum, https://forums.mysql.com/list.php?38 You might consider the vendor for support too.

Comment: Your error is reported from the AWS Aurora Server, and the database shows that it cannot be connected, so you should ask about related technologies in the mysql forum.

Comment: Opened topic in mysql forums... https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,690670,690670#msg-690670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I discovered that we were just letting C# garbage collection handle the SqlConnection object instead of properly encapsulating the object in a "using" declaration. This is a problem because until garbage collection runs and destroys the SqlConnection object, the underlying database connection is not returned to the connection pool. And so when things are especially busy we stupidly starve to death despite having a warehouse full of food because the garbage collection is deferred and the connections are not being returned to the pool in a timely fashion.

The modern C# syntax allows this really simple declaration which runs the destructor immediately when the object goes out of scope. So when the object(s) leave scope the system immediately returns the underlying connection back into the pool preventing the application from starving to death.

```
using MySqlConnection z_connection = new MySqlConnection();
...
using MySqlCommand z_command = z_connection.CreateCommand();
...
using MySqlDataReader z_reader = z_command.ExecuteReader();
...
```